# Power pivot chart with two X-axes (horizontal), possible?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Is it possible to create a Power Pivot chart which has two X-axes (i.e. horizontal axes, not vertical Y-axes!)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Format one series to plot on the secondary axis, then you can turn on the secondary X axis (click the + sign to add a chart element > Axes > tick Secondary Horizontal.

Edit: to format the series, you can right-click the series in the chart and then select "Format Data Series" in the context menu.  In the "Format Data Series" dialog or side panel (which of these you get depends on your Excel version), tick the option for "Secondary Axis" on the Series Options view.

[image]

Comment: It doesnt show that option to me ( http://i.imgur.com/pT19t8K.png ). I've tried with line, column and combo type of charts. In Pivot Chart Fields, I have two fields on Axis/Categories and two fields on Values.

Comment: How can I "format one series to plot on the secondary axis"?

Comment: Are you asking how to open the format series dialog? I'll edit my answer, but you really need to consider using a site for beginner questions instead of one for advanced programming to ask questions like that.